# play embedded mp4 video in html5 using phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video

I am trying to play embedded mp4 video in my html5 application running on android. I went though few ideas.

1. Plugin URL: https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer 
   Result: Video player working in Android environment BUT the video is playing in a separate app
2. Plugin URL: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js 
   Result: Video player not working in Android BUT working perfectly in a web browser.

BTW, I am using phonegap 2.6.0. Any leads to my solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can use plugin [FileOpener](https://github.com/michalzubkowicz/FileOpener/tree/cordova-2.8.0).   It works in android and as well as in browser i was getting so many issues to play local Video Files using Phonegap but i successfully played my local video files using [FILE OPENER PLUGIN](https://github.com/michalzubkowicz/FileOpener/tree/cordova-2.8.0)